# Read a file with script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I want to get the content of a file (as string) with google script. It's a txt or html file which I want to edit as string after.
The file is stored on Google Drive and I know the ID.

What I know that you can access the file with:

`var Template = DriveApp.getFileById('18DEuu91FJ4rhTYd-xrlNpP2U9jfyheEI');`

But I can nothing find how to read the content of this file like "file_get_contents" in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Googles Reference on the Apps Script you can use the [`getAs()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getascontenttype) method to return the file contents. I haven't tested this myself, but you could try something like:

```
var Template = DriveApp.getFileById('18DEuu91FJ4rhTYd-xrlNpP2U9jfyheEI');
var contents = Template.getAs('text/plain');
```

Comment: Yes! It works perfect! Thank you. I had no idea which string to use for searching on the net.