# How to manipulate javascript which was previously created via Google spreadsheet data conversion

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

There is a Google Spreadsheet.

[image]

Through Spreadsheet's own (bound) script, its content has been converted into a javascript file (conversion.js).
manipulator.gs:

```
function conversion() {
  const data = 
    SpreadsheetApp
      .getActiveSheet()
      .getRange("Sheet1!A1:C2")
      .getValues();
  
  const file = 
    JSON
      .stringify(data)
      .replace(/(.*)/,"const conversion = $1;");
  
  DriveApp
    .getFolderById("1kpaeLkWoSjwYGZZz7yUIKxjCY6ihVXrz")
    .createFile("conversion.js", file, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
};
```

The resulted conversion.js content is:

```
const conversion = [[11,12,13],[21,22,23]];
```

And then, I want to permanently manipulate the content of this conversion.js file.
For example:

```
conversion[1][1] = "test";
```

I don't mind where the conversion.js file has to be located for its manipulation:-

- In its current place in Google Drive or
- In the Script editor as a separate file (conversion.gs) next to manipulator.gs

I just need to copy/paste the content of the manipulated file.

```
const conversion = [[11,12,13],[21,"test",23]];
```

Comment: So copy paste. Is there a problem?

Comment: @TheMaster The desired content is not available. I cannot manipulate the converted file. I have this: [21,22,23], but I need this: [21,"test",23].

Comment: I don't understand your question to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to replace an element of the 2d **data** array you need to run this:

```
data[1].splice(1,1, "test")
```

before the creation of `const file`.

Try the following and you will get the desired result:

```
function conversion() {
  const data = 
    SpreadsheetApp
      .getActiveSheet()
      .getRange("Sheet1!A1:C2")
      .getValues();
  
  data[1].splice(1,1, "test")
  
  const file = 
    JSON
      .stringify(data)
      .replace(/(.*)/,"const conversion = $1;");
  

  DriveApp
    .getFolderById("1kpaeLkWoSjwYGZZz7yUIKxjCY6ihVXrz")
    .createFile("conversion.js", file, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
};
```

**Result:**

[image: Result of the code]

> **References:**

[arr.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 1):

### If you want to update the content of a file you created on your Drive, you have two possibilities

**1. More complicated but elegant**

- Perform a File PATCH request to the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/patch) with the [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61727638/how-to-insert-file-to-a-shared-drive-using-rest-on-apps-script/61776451#61776451) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61797113/change-file-name-of-file-uploaded-using-google-drive-api-apps-script)

**2. Easier**

- Read the file in as e.g. done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462391/read-a-file-with-script)
- Modify the content as needed
- Overwrite the existing file with a new one with the updated content